# How to kill setInterval() inside Vue Js instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with a countdown function I've created for an idiotic fight game I'm developing as an assignment.

I have the following method:

```js
/* Countdown timer before fight */

    startTimer() {
        this.countDownPanel = true;
        if (this.countDownNumbers > 0) {
            this.countDown = setInterval(() => {
                this.countDownNumbers--;
            }, 1000);
            this.textDownsizer = setInterval(() => {
                this.countDownTextSize--;
            }, 10);
        }
    },
```

And the following watcher that stops the countdown:

```js
  /* Countdown Watcher */

    countDownNumbers() {
        this.countDownTextSize = 100;
        if (this.countDownNumbers < 0) {
            clearInterval(this.textDownsizer);
            this.textDownsizer = null;
            clearInterval(this.countDown);
            this.countDown = null;
            this.countDownPanel = false;
        }
    }
},
```

The problem is that even after I use the clearInterval() through the Vue DevTools I can see the timer still running until countDownNumbers reaches 0. But the case is that it happens a while after the actual numbers on the screen are down to 0. And when I reset the game, running the same instance, the countdown goes nuts and causes a memory leak. Is there a better way of doing it?

Here's the complete Js code:

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    gameStatus: 'disclaimer', //Status of the app, it can be (so far) 'disclaimer', 'startScreen', 'playStage', 'looseScreen', 'wonScreen', 'menuScreen'
    backgroundAudio: new Array(), //Array of current playing background sounds
    blurFilter: true, //Blur shown at the start of the app
    audioTracks: ["sound/battle.mp3", "sound/dungeon.wav", "sound/echo.ogg"], //List of file in the folder 'sound'
    playList: new Array(), //Array with a collection of Audio objects that are playable
    /* 
    The health points function in an inverse way. The subject dies when it reaches 100
    The health bar div width % is calculated subtracting the current health of the avatar of 100. 
    */
    healthHuman: 0,
    healthComputer: 0,
    muted: false, //Obviously determines if the audio is activated or not
    humanStatus: true, //Defines if the human player is dead or alive
    computerStatus: true, //Defines if the computer player is dead or alive

    /* Collection of string that are outputed when a avatar dies */
    humanDiesPhrases: [
        "You've just been killed and that's why you're seeing your own life flash in front of you.",
        "It's almost as if your soul has taken over your body in a frantic attempt to preserve the memory of what you love.",
        "The problem is that when your soul leaves your body, it's physically incapable of going back in and if it doesn't try to go back in and make the same decision, it could start experiencing the same things all over again.",
        "That was sad and gruesome and an almost poetic way. Anyway, you're dead. The rats are anxious to eat your remains.",
        "Looks like the monster will be eating something besides rats today",
        "Woow! That must have hurted! Dude! Are you okay? Dude? Dude... Ohh, you're dead. Sorry about that",
        "Your death looks like an abstract painting. To me, not for you. For you that must have hurted like hell.",
        "Yep! Looks like you're dead. Can I have your sowrd?",
        "You died! Was killed to be more exact. Now your opponent drags you to one of many dark pits inside the dungeon.",
        "Oh my god, how can you suck in such idiotic game? I know that the game is lame, but you just raised the bar fella.",
        "You're not very good at this are you? Have you ever considered trying gardening?"
    ],
    computerDiesPhrases: [
        "You've just killed it! Or should I say him? Or her? You didn't ask, did you? How considerate of you.",
        "GG mah boy, keep it like this and I'm sure you're going places. Maybe...",
        "Wow that was 2 minutes less of your life, how does it feel? You're not having those back... Are you still reading?",
        "Oh my, my... Why such violence? Have you considered petting it? Maybe it was just saying hello. Weirdo.",
        "Well, it's dead. Now what? Are you going to eat it? Of course not silly, this is just a game. Back to being productive",
        "AM I being nosy or you should be doind something else instead? I mean, killing virtual monsters?",
        "Good kill dude! But, have you considered that it maybe was the last of its kind? That's disturbing.",
        "You've just killed the creature! Good for you girl!",
        "Wait! Have you considered trying to... Forget it, it's dead already",
        "Oh man! (or woman!). That was gruesome. Wait a minute, have you just farted? Ewww! Ohh sorry, that one was mine.",
        "Why did you do that? Such violence. Well you killed it, just like that. That's aliens haven't made contact with us yet...Savage!"
    ],
    humanParts: [
        "groin", "left eye", "upper lip", "right ear", "left leg", "tiny finger", "balls", "right knee", "face", "head", "lung", "chest", "chin", "middle finger", "you know where", "neck", "nose", "foot", "ribs", "teeth",
    ],
    monsterParts: [
        "center most tentacle", "foremost tooth", "tiny tentacle", "lady parts", "boy parts", "gum", "ass", "iris", "eyeball", "feelings", "wise tooth"
    ],
    fightingMovements: [
        "bite", "slapped", "punched", "kicked", "headbutted", "scratched", "hit", "punctured", "fingered", "poundded", "bashed"
    ],
    countDownNumbers: 5, //Countdown counter =)
    countDown: '', //Stores the main countdown
    countDownTextSize: 100, //Obvious
    textDownsizer: '', //Stores the timer responsible to downsize the font of the countdown
    logger: new Array(), //Array responsible for storing all messages that will be shown to the player
    countDownPanel: false, //Determines if the countdown is to be shown or not

},
computed: {

    /* Unset the blur when the disclaimer modal goes away */

    flipBlur() {
        if (this.gameStatus != 'disclaimer') {
            return this.blurFilter = false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    },
},
watch: {
    //Wacth the gameStatus and make changes accordingly
    gameStatus() {

        //Background Audio Controler

        //Tracks
        echoSound = this.playList['echo'];
        battleSound = this.playList['battle'];
        dungeonSound = this.playList['dungeon'];

        //Game status DJ
        if (this.gameStatus == 'startScreen') {
            this.loopPlay(echoSound);
            this.loopPlay(dungeonSound);
        } else if (this.gameStatus == 'playStage') {

            //Add battle song to the background

            this.loopPlay(battleSound);
            battleSound.volume = 0.25;

            //Trigger the coundown
            this.startTimer();
        }
    },

    muted() {
        if (this.muted == true) {
            this.backgroundAudio.forEach(element => {
                element.pause();
            });
        } else {
            this.backgroundAudio.forEach(element => {
                element.play();
            });
        }
    },

    /* Health checkers // Killer */

    healthHuman() {
        if (this.healthHuman >= 100) {
            this.healthHuman = 100;
            this.humanStatus = false;
            this.humanDied();
        }
    },

    healthComputer() {
        if (this.healthComputer >= 100) {
            this.healthComputer = 100;
            this.computerStatus = false;
            this.computerDied();
        }
    },

    /* Logger Wachter  - Maintain only the last 3 elements of the logger */

    logger() {
        if (this.logger.length > 3) {
            this.logger.pop();
        }
    },


    /* Countdown Watcher */

    countDownNumbers() {
        this.countDownTextSize = 100;
        if (this.countDownNumbers < 0) {
            clearInterval(this.textDownsizer);
            this.textDownsizer = null;
            clearInterval(this.countDown);
            this.countDown = null;
            this.countDownPanel = false;
        }
    }
},

beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.textDownsizer);
},

created: function () {
    this.buildPlayList();
},

methods: {

    /* Background soundtracks and sound effects */

    loopPlay(audioTrack) {
        if (audioTrack) {
            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.loop = true;
            this.backgroundAudio.push(audioTrack);
        }
    },

    buildPlayList() {
        this.audioTracks.forEach(element => {
            trackName = element.substring(element.indexOf('/') + 1);
            trackName = trackName.substring(0, trackName.indexOf('.'));
            this.playList[trackName] = new Audio(element);
        });
    },

    /*
     HP monitoring and controller
     These two functions return the css property 'width' of the health bars.
     */

    heartMonitorHuman() {
        return {
            width: this.healthHuman + '%'
        }
    },

    heartMonitorComputer() {
        return {
            width: this.healthComputer + '%'
        }
    },

    /* Generates random hit points */

    hitGenerator() {
        var hit = Math.round(Math.random() * 20);
        return hit;
    },

    /* Controlls the timer before the fight */

    counterFontSize() {
        return {
            'fontSize': this.countDownTextSize + 'vw'
        }
    },

    /* Hits the human */

    hitHuman() {
        if (this.healthHuman < 100) {
            var willHitPoints = Math.floor(this.hitGenerator() * 1.1); //Gives the monster 10% more attack power on average
            this.healthHuman += willHitPoints;
            this.logHandler('You got ' + this.randomFightingMoves() + ' on the ' + this.humanHitDesc() + ' and lost ' + willHitPoints + ' HP');


        } else {
            this.humanDied();
        }
    },

    /* Hits the computer */

    hitComputer() {
        if (this.healthComputer < 100 && this.countDownNumbers <= 0) {
            var willHitPoints = this.hitGenerator();
            this.healthComputer += willHitPoints;
            this.logHandler('You ' + this.randomFightingMoves() + ' the monster\'s ' + this.monsterHitDesc() + ' and it lost ' + willHitPoints + ' HP');

            //Hits the human player back

            this.hitHuman();

        } else {
            this.computerDied();
        }
    },

    /* Shows phrases regarding the avatar's deaths */

    humanDied() {
        if (this.humanStatus == false) {
            var deathMessage = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            this.logHandler(this.humanDiesPhrases[deathMessage]);
            this.logHandler("You died!");
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.resetGame();
            }, 3000);
        }
    },

    computerDied() {
        if (this.computerStatus == false) {
            var deathMessage = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            this.logHandler(this.computerDiesPhrases[deathMessage]);
            this.logHandler("You win?");
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.resetGame();
            }, 3000);
        }
    },

    /* Generates a random key to be used with a dictionary of log messages */

    keyGen() {
        return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    },

    /* Creates a dictionary with all log messages generated by the app */

    logHandler(msg) {
        var newLog = {
            id: this.keyGen(),
            message: msg,
        };
        this.logger.unshift(newLog);
    },

    /* Random hits generators */

    humanHitDesc() {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
        return this.humanParts[randomNumber];
    },

    monsterHitDesc() {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        return this.monsterParts[randomNumber];
    },

    randomFightingMoves() {
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        return this.fightingMovements[randomNumber];
    },

    resetGame() {
        this.logger = [];
        this.healthHuman = 0;
        this.humanStatus = true;
        this.healthComputer = 0;
        this.computerStatus = true;
        this.countDownNumbers = 5;
        this.startTimer();
    },

    /* Countdown timer before fight */

    startTimer() {
        this.countDownPanel = true;
        if (this.countDownNumbers > 0) {
            this.countDown = setInterval(() => {
                this.countDownNumbers--;
            }, 1000);
            this.textDownsizer = setInterval(() => {
                this.countDownTextSize--;
            }, 10);
        }
    },
}
});
```

The GitHub repo is: https://github.com/Saiuke/MonsterSlayer

Here's a screen capture of the game:

[image: Monster Slayer screen capture showing the countdown before the fight.]

Comment: I'd guess that `countDownNumbers` is a function, so `this.countDownNumbers < 0` is never true

Comment: and why do you need to `this.countDownTextSize = this.countDownTextSize` ??? that makes zero sense - `this.countDownTextSize` already and always is `this.countDownTextSize`

Comment: Sorry, actually it's this.countDownTextSize-- (or -10, before). Already fixed it. I was trying some ideas and forgot to hit CRTL+Z. And, countDownNumbers is a property of the object, is the variable that stores the current number of the countdown, so it goes 5, 4, 3...

Comment: If you want help, I'd suggest posting actual code in the question - maybe there's something else you've put wrong in the question

Comment: I have just added the entire Js code, I hope it may help to understand the problem somehow. But for a more complete understandment I think that would be better to download the  GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

edited: sorry for the mistake. its fixed now.

Have you tried changing if (this.countDownNumbers < 0) to if (this.countDownNumbers === 0)? That might work. If that does not work then why not just make a simple countdown like this:

```
let num = 10;

let timer = setInterval(function(){
    num = num - 1;
    console.log(num);

    if(num <= 0){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Basically, what I have is a version of what you suggested. I think that the problem I have has to do with the way Vue Js works somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that `startTimer()` does not stop any existing timers before starting new ones. And since `startTimer()` is indirectly invoked by the user (i.e., `humanDied() -> resetGame() -> startTimer()`, `computerDied() -> resetGame() -> startTimer()`, or `gameStatus change -> startTimer()`), multiple timers can be started unpredictably.

The solution is to stop any existing timers before starting new ones, and to move the expiration logic from the `countdownTimer` watcher into `startTimer()`:

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    countDownNumbers() {
      this.countDownTextSize = 100;

      // XXX: DON'T DO THIS HERE
      // if (this.countDownNumbers < 0) {
      //   clearInterval(this.textDownsizer);
      //   this.textDownsizer = null;
      //   clearInterval(this.countDown);
      //   this.countDown = null;
      //   this.countDownPanel = false;
      // }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    startTimer() {
      clearInterval(this.countDown);
      this.countDown = null;
      clearInterval(this.textDownsizer);
      this.textDownsizer = null;

      if (this.countDownNumbers > 0) {
        this.countDown = setInterval(() => {
          this.countDownNumbers--;

          if (countDownNumbers <= 0) {
            this.countDownPanel = false;
          }
        }, 1000);

        this.textDownsizer = setInterval(() => {
          this.countDownTextSize--;
        }, 10);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But then I don't have a moment where the countDownTextSize is reseted to 100. The idea is that for each second that passes by a big number (100vw) appear on the screen, and then it's sized down to 0. Right after that, the number value is increased and its font size is reset to 100.

Comment: Anyway, with some adjustments, your suggestion is working. The main problem still persists, that is the timer appearing on the screen is not synchronized with the data shown by the Vue DevTool. That causes an annoying bug that if the 'fight' is ended before said lag shown in the Vue DevTools the timers ignore all the if and keep running forever.

Answer (score 0):

you can do by this way it is so easy. this code is compatible with **Vue-Js 3**.

```
...... youe code......
  ,mounted() {
      this.intervalId = setInterval(this.callStatusFn, 200)
      console.log("intervalId "+ this.intervalId)
},
unmounted() {
  clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  }
```